# can't publish allure report in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, allure

we are using [Allure Test Report](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Molecula.allure-test-reports) plugin for this purpose. However this fails with below error
[image: ADO error]
[image: ADO error continuation]

Can somebody help us find a way to overcome this issue or any other approach to publish the Allure generated artifact in ADO pipeline

Comment: Please paste the text logs as a code section instead of using an image. It's easier to read, more inclusive and can be indexed by a search engine.

Comment: Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/919

Answer (score 0):

move this is as TASK inside your Job test, or whatever is running the test.
Then cd into the location where your allure bat file is
from there just run
allure generate result-directory -o report-directory --clean

your publish task needs to happen right after. You can get the generated results from the  into the desired location of the publish